# empty quotes in $_POST array php

Tags: php, syntax

This is the entire contents of my `$_Post` array

```
'name' => 'Jon Doe'
'email' => 'jon@jondoe.com' 
'age' => 22
'action' => ''
```

What value will `$action` have after the following PHP statement is executed?

```
$action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];
```

Comment: That depends on what the value of `$_POST['action']` is.

Comment: I reckon it would have been quicker to try it yourself...

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, please tag it as homework. Incidentally, this is a great time to fire up a PHP interpreter with `php -a` and just type in your problem to test output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** (emphasis) the code sample is the output from the $_POST array, the value after the ternary expression will be 'default' ... though it's worth noting that you don't need the parentheses around the condition, so you could change it to:

```
$action = empty($_POST['action']) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];
```

Comment: @T.Rob thanks for fixing my brain spazz. Apparently I'm the only person who got the memo that "parentheses" are now referred to as "quotes" :)

Comment: Actually if you look at the edit history, I was correcting @vascowhite who thought they were brackets.  Apparently there are 254 different memos floating around.  Apparently you got Memo 0x22 and he got Memo 0x5B.  Either that or there was a distributed brain spazz and you two participated in the same unit of work. Hooray for high availability!

Comment: Hehe, it's always the small things that are the most amusing

Answer (score 1):

default

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php